# Storing the each output into a variable

Tags: bash, variable, for

I have script here that will list the date that the user will enter and output the date  5 days ago.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What month?"
            echo "1 - January"
            echo "2 - February"
            echo "3 - March"
            echo "4 - April"
            echo "5 - May"
            echo "6 - June"
            echo "7 - July"
            echo "8 - August"
            echo "9 - September"
            echo "10 - October"
            echo "11 - November"
            echo "12 - December"
            echo ""
            echo -n "What month?  "
            read m

            if [ "$m" == "1" ]
            then
            mn="Jan "
            elif [ "$m" == "2" ]
            then
            mn="Feb "
            elif [ "$m" == "3" ]
            then
            mn="Mar "
            elif [ "$m" == "4" ]
            then
            mn="Apr "
            elif [ "$m" == "5" ]
            then
            mn="May "
            elif [ "$m" == "6" ]
            then
            mn="Jun "
            elif [ "$m" == "7" ]
            then
            mn="Jul "
            elif [ "$m" == "8" ]
            then
            mn="Aug "
            elif [ "$m" == "9" ]
            then
            mn="Sep "
            elif [ "$m" == "10" ]
            then
            mn="Oct "
            elif [ "$m" == "11" ]
            then
            mn="Nov "
            elif [ "$m" == "12" ]
            then
            mn="Dec "
            else
            echo "Invalid month"
            fi
            echo ""

            #DAY
            echo -n "What day? "
            read d
            if [ "$d" -lt "9" ]
            then
                    mnd="$mn"" ""$d"
            elif [ "$d"  -gt "31" ]
            then
                    mnd="1"
            else
                    mnd="$mn""$d"
            fi



 for dy in {0..4}; do
    date -d "$mn $d - $dy days" +'%b %_d'
 done
```

Output:

```
What month?
8
What day?
1

Aug  1
Jul 31
Jul 30
Jul 29
Jul 28
```

What I want now is to store each date in to variable for example 
the first line must `Aug 1` must be stored on variable `x1` 
`Jul 31` must be stored on variable `x2` etc.. What I mean whatever output on the first list must be stored on `x1` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead of trying to create separate variables.

```
declare -a x

for dy in {0..4}; do
  x+=( "$( date -d "$mn $d - $dy days" +'%b %_d' )" )
done
```

You may then access the four values in `${x[0]}` through to `${x[3]}`.

For the first part of your script, have you considered using a `select` statement?

```
select mn in "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" \
             "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
do
  if [[ -z "$mn" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid choice" >&2
  else
    break
  fi
done

printf "You selected '%s'\n" "$mn"
```

This does the following:

```
1) Jan    3) Mar   5) May   7) Jul   9) Sep  11) Nov
2) Feb    4) Apr   6) Jun   8) Aug  10) Oct  12) Dec
#? 56
Invalid choice
#? 5
You selected 'May'
```

The value of `$mn` will be the selected string (`May` for example).

Comment: Will this actually I'm looking for. I can't explain more further earlier  the `i++` hahaha.

Comment: for the first part of my script I already have that `if..else statement` is under of `select statement`

Comment: how can the variable? is right? `echo ${x[0]}` ?

Comment: @JJ-SAMA `echo "${x[0]}"` outputs the first value in the array `x`.  The `select` statement replaces your `if ... then ... else` statements.

Comment: I tried this code but I cant get the value.
`declare -a x

for dy in {0..4}; do
   x+=$(date -d "$mn $d - $dy days" +'%b %_d')
done

echo "${x[0]}"
echo ""
echo "${x[3]}"
`

Comment: it echo only this `Aug  1Jul 31Jul 30Jul 29Jul 28


`

Comment: including space...

Comment: @JJ-SAMA Sorry, I made a typo. It's fixed now.